# I can't use the property of the Tempdata in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a button for dequeuing my data from static variable, then I need to render a specific property on my view but for some reason I can't render it even if I already use the name space.

Here is my Controller :

```
    public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();

        TempData["QueueItem"] = first;

        return PartialView("_queuenumber");
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
        @{
            var item = (MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
        }
        <p>@item.QueueNumber</p>
```

Here is my Class:

```
public class MyQueue
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MyQueueId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string QueueNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1:000}", ServiceLetter ?? "?", MyQueueId);
        }
        set { }
    }

    public static Queue<MyQueue> todayQueue = new Queue<MyQueue>();

    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceLetter { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

This looks good and working but for some reason Im getting an error.
The error looks like this.

Error Message:
"The type or namespace name 'MyQueue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give Full Reference of your assembly to the class

```
 @{
        var item = (Namespace.MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
  }
```

In the view Class library reference are not directly accessible so you need to give a full reference to your class

Comment: it works but my second error was in <p>@item.QueueNumber</p>
object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: it was null atm cuz I'm not yet enqueuing any data. how can I handle it?

Comment: You can check it of null before rendering it like @if{ item != null } { //code here }

Comment: how can I handle if its null cause its returning me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when I use it in my Index view

Comment: yes the previous answer that i gave was for any kind of view either index or some else. the same razor syntax is used @if(item != null ){ //code here }

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify or import your namespace in your view. either you can specify like @Ahsam Aslam's answer or you can specify your namespace `using` and also you can use `as`  keyword to conversions between compatible reference types or nullable types.

for example your namespace is `DataStructure` then

```
@using DataStructure
@{
        var item = TempData["QueueItem"] as MyQueue;
 }
```

like this your can convert your `TempData` into compatible reference type.

i hope it should helps you let me know if require more information.